# Apply an operation on pandas DataFrame rows based on a Series that matchs the number of columns of the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Let's say that I have a DataFrame df and a Series s like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,3), columns=["A", "B", "C"])
>>> df
          A         B         C
0 -0.625816  0.793552 -1.519706
1 -0.955960  0.142163  0.847624
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

I'd like to add the values of s to each row in df. I guess I should use some apply with axis=1 or applymap but I can't figure out how (do I have to transpose at some point?).

Actually my problem is more complex that that and the final DataFrame will be composed of the elements of the initial DataFrame that will have been processed according to the values of two Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is add 1d numpy array created from Series for prevent alignment columns of DataFrame to index of Series:

```
df = df + s.values
print (df)
          A         B         C
0  0.207070  1.995021  4.829518
1  0.819741  2.802982  2.801355
```

If same columns and index values it working with `sum`:

```
#index is same like columns names
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=df.columns)
print (s)
A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64

df = df + s
```